# How to create animation splash screen in flutter for desktop application like discord destop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-desktop

**I want to show a splash screen like discord splash screen  with animation  in flutter  desktop app.  i already used that package**  [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash/changelog)  **for android and ios app but that package   could not   work in   windows and   mac  application.  so  any  have  idea how too  craete  the  splash screen  for desktop appliction  like desktop discord application**

[image]